# Jquery data attribute value equals

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below are my requirements.. i tried in below way. it doesnt work for me. Please let me know what is missed out. Thanks

1. if data-block = 1, add data-rewardpoints = 300
2. if data-block = 2, add data-rewardpoints = 400
3. if data-block = 3, add data-rewardpoints = 500

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ir_image_holder">
  <img class="ir_img_src" src="1.jpg" data-block="1" data-rewardpoints="" />
</div>
<div class="ir_image_holder">
  <img class="ir_img_src" src="2.jpg" data-block="2" data-rewardpoints="" />
</div>
<div class="ir_image_holder">
  <img class="ir_img_src" src="3.jpg" data-block="3" data-rewardpoints="" />
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
if ($('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').data('block')===1) {
    $('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').attr('data-rewardpoints', '300');
} else if ($('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').data('block')===2) {
    $('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').attr('data-rewardpoints', '400');
} else if ($('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').data('block')===3) {
    $('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').attr('data-rewardpoints', '500');
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that data is stored as string. So you are comparing a string value to an integer.  Try  === "1" etc.

Comment: dont use === use == cause triple equals means you are comparing everything of theirs , ie: data type, value, etc...

Comment: Hi.. anything is possible.. Just need to add rewardpoints based on block value. either string or integer is ok

Comment: Try to alert OR console first about data block like alert($('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').data('block')) and see is it give you expected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do some thing like this

```
// Get all matched element
var elem = $('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src');
// loop through each o fthem to get the data-block value
 $(elem).each(function(e,v){
 if($(this).data('block')===1){
    // assign the data-reward point here
    $(this).attr('data-rewardpoints',300);
 }
// rest of code

})
```

Comment: Thanks for your help bro!!

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this you need to loop over all the `.ir_img_src` elements individually. Right now your code is setting all the elements `data()` attributes based on the first element of the set.

You can also tidy the logic by holding all the values to set in an object keyed by the `block`. Try this:

```js
var data = { 1: 300, 2: 400, 3: 500 }

$('.ir_img_src').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-rewardpoints', data[$(this).data('block')]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ir_image_holder">
  <img class="ir_img_src" src="1.jpg" data-block="1" data-rewardpoints="" />
</div>
<div class="ir_image_holder">
  <img class="ir_img_src" src="2.jpg" data-block="2" data-rewardpoints="" />
</div>
<div class="ir_image_holder">
  <img class="ir_img_src" src="3.jpg" data-block="3" data-rewardpoints="" />
</div>
```

Note that it's considered better practice to use the setter of `data()` instead of `attr()`, where possible. I've left your code as-is here, as there are certain cases where you have to use `attr()` to set the data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try iterating over all elements

```
$('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').each(function() {
  if($( this ).data('block') == "1") {
     $( this ).attr('data-rewardpoints', '300');
  }
  else if($( this ).data('block') == "2") {
     $( this ).attr('data-rewardpoints', '400');
  }
  else if($( this ).data('block') == "3") {
     $( this ).attr('data-rewardpoints', '500');
  }
});
```

Comment: you can/should always use data block with jQuery standard way as provided https://api.jquery.com/data/ here

Answer (score 0):

Your selector selects all elements that match it and not a single one, which is the expectation of the JS snippet you've provided.

I assume you want the image to be clicked and then to perform the operation in your JS snippet. Here's how you can do it:

```
$('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').on('click', function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.data('block')===1) {
        $el.attr('data-rewardpoints', '300');
    } else if ($el.data('block')===2) {
        $el.attr('data-rewardpoints', '400');
    } else if ($el.data('block')===3) {
        $el.attr('data-rewardpoints', '500');
    }
});
```

If you're just trying to initialize them then iterate over all selected elements.

```
$('.ir_image_holder .ir_img_src').each(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    if ($el.data('block')===1) {
        $el.attr('data-rewardpoints', '300');
    } else if ($el.data('block')===2) {
        $el.attr('data-rewardpoints', '400');
    } else if ($el.data('block')===3) {
        $el.attr('data-rewardpoints', '500');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you just want to compare similar values, why not use [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp) instead of `if`

```js
$('.ir_img_src').each(function(e,v){
    var me = $(this);
    var db = parseInt($(this).attr('data-block'));
  
     switch(db)
     {
         case 1 : me.attr('data-rewardpoints', '300');
                  break;
         
         case 2 : me.attr('data-rewardpoints', '400');
                  break;
         
         case 3 : me.attr('data-rewardpoints', '500');
                  break;
     }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ir_image_holder">
  <img class="ir_img_src" src="1.jpg" data-block="1" data-rewardpoints="" />
</div>
<div class="ir_image_holder">
  <img class="ir_img_src" src="2.jpg" data-block="2" data-rewardpoints="" />
</div>
<div class="ir_image_holder">
  <img class="ir_img_src" src="3.jpg" data-block="3" data-rewardpoints="" />
</div>
```